# create an alias to rsync local directory with a remote server - is it bad practice?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

disclaimer: I am no superuser.

question: I find myself writing out this beast every time I want to sync up my server with my dev directories on my machine:

```
rsync -chavzP --stats user@host:/remote/ ~/local/
```

Is it bad practice to just create an alias in my .zshrc or something so I dont have to type this everytime? The username and hostname are always tricky and filled with digits. I just find myself having to look it up most of the time. If it is bad form, which I sense it is, what are some other approaches I should take to save time?

Comment: I would say yes, the aliases are here to save your typing. But if you are just interested in the host/user, you can make them aliases in `ssh_config`, if it would help you (see manual pages).

Comment: yeah, the real pain point is with the user and host. thanks for the ssh config tip

Answer (score 2):

When I first started using the Bash shell many years ago, I was reluctant to define aliases to use in case I became dependent on them and would then find myself lost if on a different system which didn’t have my shell aliases defined.

For repeating complicated commands such as your `rsync` command, I used the <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> feature in Bash which allows searching backwards through the shell history for a previously entered command.

However, this is not reliable and after a few years, I came to the conclusion that not using aliases was just being silly. They were invented decades ago (we can thank Bill Joy, creator of the C shell<sup>†</sup>) – for a very good reason: it takes time and effort to type long commands.

Most people can’t easily remember long commands, particularly if they only use them sporadically and the above `rsync` command is a perfect use case for an alias since it also doesn’t need any arguments (in which case, a shell function would be used).

Also, if you need to use a similar command, having aliases stored in your shell start-up files saves time as you don’t have to look up the details of the command from an external source.

These days, it’s common for users to store their custom shell aliases, functions, configuration files and scripts on a server so that they can be retrieved when using a new or different system. Some use Dropbox, others GitHub, while others upload them to their own personal web space. That way, their shell customisations are always available to them.

#### Conclusion/TLDR

Using such aliases is good practice, saves time and typing – and is the reason they were created. Saving them in shell start-up files such as `.zshrc` means they’ll always be available to you and is considered best practice for users of Unix shells.

#### See also

[When to alias, when to script, and when to write a function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)

#### Reference

**<sup>†</sup>** Here’s what Bill Joy says about aliases in his [Introduction to the C shell](http://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/usd/04.csh/paper.html):

> This mechanism can be used to simplify the commands you type, to supply default arguments to commands, or to perform transformations on commands and their arguments.

Comment: not to mention tab-completion. On most reasonable systems now you need only know the first 3-4 letters of the command and the location of the tab key. In other words, well said.. : )